# Swift 3 Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '__OS_dispatch_queue_attr?'

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a problem with this line which is ok in swift 2 but not in swift 3

```
let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

 videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue_create("sample buffer delegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL))
```

It doesn't work in Swift 3 - error :
**Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '__OS_dispatch_queue_attr?**

Does anyone know how to fix it ?